# Two repositories for one project

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I currently have a project in Visual Studio that's tied to a private repository on Visual Studio Online (TFS). I'd also like to have the same project (minus a few differences) as a public project on GitHub. What's the easiest way to accomplish this so I don't have separate projects locally. (one for TFS and one for GitHub)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do it is have a branch for what I want visible in GitHub and then when I'm ready to push updates there I merge into my GitHub branch and publish that branch to GitHub (GitHub is one of the remotes in my local setup).

Comment: this solution works great. Sorry for the delay in accepting your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could put the bulk of the project - the common stuff, into a git submodule.  Then you would have two repos (public and private) that both include it.